# Copy file before include it in the installer package NSIS

Tags: file, copy, nsis

For example I have a config file in D:\Project\InstallerPro\Platform\Windows8\Web.config
I need to move that file to D:\Project\InstallerPro\Web\Configuration\Web.config if the windows version is windows 8

After that, the installer will be generated from a nsi script in D:\Project\InstallerPro\PROinst.nsi

Is it possible to copy the files (not manually) before compiling it into an installer using NSIS?

I want to do something like this:

```
CopyFiles ".\Source\Platform\Windows8\Web.config" ".\Source\WEB\Configuration\Web.config"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CopyFiles` is a runtime command, i.e a command that will run during the installer execution and not during the installer creation.

You could use the `!system` command that is executed during the compilation of the installer, e.g.:

```
!system `copy "c:\Source\Platform\Windows8\Web.config" "c:\Source\WEB\Configuration\Web.config"`
```

You will need to use *absolute paths* as the current working dir is from `makensis.exe` and not from the script being compiled.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Seki and I am wondering is it better to put the copy code inside the script or put it in C# application? Because I have a C# application which is used to compile different installer script based on user's preferences.

Comment: @currarpickt: I would say it depends on you needs. NSIS is quite limited on the commands it can perform at compile time beside deleting file, executing a system command... (see [Compile Time Commands](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html)) If your pre-processing workflow needs elaborated steps, it could be better to keep it in a separated program / script more expressive than nsis script. Here I need to refresh SVN repos before and perform some tests and notifications after setup compilation and I use some external Perl scripts, where NSIS compilation is one of the steps.